# How to hide the login button on my personal blog

Tags: google-app-engine

I decided to implement a blog system on Google AppEngine. But:

1. I don't want to add a login button on my blog.
2. I don't want to provide a url to type in manually to login.

But I still want to do admin things ONLINE and only for myself, e.g. posting, editing, deleting and etc.

Any clever ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a component to the web page template that is only rendered if you are an admin.

For example, in your HTML template if you have something like this it'll only render the content if admin_bool is True. So you can put a form etc inside there and only you'll see it.

```
    {% if admin_bool %}
        # only show this if you are an admin
    {% endif %}
```

So if you happen to be using the GAE users service you can do this:

```
    from google.appengine.api import users

    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        print "Welcome, %s!" % user.nickname()
    if users.is_current_user_admin():
        admin_bool = True
```

and pass admin_bool to your template and it'll render only if the current user is an admin.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/usingusers.html#tutorials-gettingstarted-usingusers

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html#tutorials-gettingstarted-templates

Comment: To use `users.is_current_user_admin()` to check whether you are a admin or not you have to login first. Where to login if I don't provide the login button and url?

Comment: well, you don't want to implement a log in interface but you have to log in somewhere. So with these scheme you at least have to be logged into your google account. Whatever you do, if it get's popular you must have a proper auth scheme. You can hide something in the code for now, but someone will find it. And if you are logged into google and your google account is set as admin then the admin interface will appear in your app automatically.

Comment: `And if you are logged into google and your google account is set as admin then the admin interface will appear in your app automatically.` This is what I want. I thought login to your google account does not automatically login to your app. 'Cause I thought you have to login each app explicitly and separately. I will try.

Comment: :P OK, just wait for a few days. I will have to first verify the login thing. 'Cause I saw somewhere that explicit login is required for every app you own.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason of not providing a secret URL that simply is not shown anywhere and then simply having for your admin pages the [administrator required](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status) in your app.yaml, like this:

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin
```

But if you really really want to not provide anything you can still do that. Don't forget that you are allowed to deploy up to 10 different versions for the same application on Google App Engine with unique URLs that can be accessed like this:

```
http://version-name.application-name.appspot.com
```

So you can create a totally different application to administrate your site and another application to present it. Deploy them both on the same app and having the right one as a default version.

Comment: More or less the same solution as akton's. I dont like login button because I think it's of no use to the viewers.

Comment: @gb18030 Well he was saying about the same app.. just hiding the URL, which I support of course... but you can deploy a totally different application.. so the blog part will have nothing on how to admin the site..!

Comment: On a second thought, great! :) I've nenver thought of creating a separate app for admin. I will consider this.

Comment: @gb18030 If it's going to be only for you.. you don't have to put much effort on making it great or secure.. if you set up the `login: admin` Google will make sure only you will be able to login (or any of the admins of the app)

Answer (score 0):

Provide a different page or URL that shows the login button for the admin features of the blog. For example, a blog can be hosted on wordpress.com, where the admin can login, but accessed by a different URL that does not expose the login button.

Comment: Might be a solution. So anyway it seems that I've got to login somewhere. ==b

Answer (score 0):

You could use a keyboard shortcut. Or an invisible button. Maybe a gesture.

Comment: I actually think about this. It's just that I've yet figured out a novel way to implement this :)

Comment: It depends how much the login button should be protected. A keyboard shortcut, invisible button or gesture would be revealed by looking at the page's code.

Comment: @akton Well, the security may not be an issue, because on appengine, it's left to google. I just want to remove the login button totally or implement it in a funny way.